# Depends what is on Picklist Input, write text into Minimum and Maximum currency fields

Tags: visualforce

```
  <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Proposal_Grade__c}"/> 
  <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Funding_Estimate_Range_Minimum__c}" label="Proposal Minimum"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Funding_Estimate_Range_Maximum__c}" label="Proposal Maximum"/>
```

Depends of value in Proposal Grade, should populate it should populate in Minimum in Maximum default value. There is example on image. So if in proposal grade there is Proposal Grade ="80k-100k", minimum will be 80k and maximum will be 100k. Proposal Grade is picklist and has some default values so i can use like that.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is exactly your objective? to give a value to the currency fields?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can modify your code in a following way

```
<apex:inputField value="{!lead.Proposal_Grade__c}"> 
    <apex:actionSupport event="change" action="{!onPGChange}" rerender="fields"/>
</apex:inputField>
<apex:outputPanel id="fields">
    <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Funding_Estimate_Range_Minimum__c}" label="Proposal Minimum"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!lead.Funding_Estimate_Range_Maximum__c}" label="Proposal Maximum"/>  
</apex:outputPanel>
```

and write a new method inside of your apex controller class

```
public void onPGChange() {
    String[] values =  lead.Proposal_Grade__c.split('-');
    lead.Funding_Estimate_Range_Minimum__c = values[0];
    lead.Funding_Estimate_Range_Maximum__c = values[1];
}
```

Comment: Got message in controller, method does not exist on incorrect signature...

Comment: Did you copy the method to your controller?